# bootstrap.min.css is overriding my custom css file

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, web, overriding

I know my question is similar to: [Bootstrap popup does not appear when include bootstrap.min.css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32230679/bootstrap-popup-does-not-appear-when-include-bootstrap-min-css)
However it was not resolved and I am practically having the same issue (minus the JS).

I am currently designing my Bootstrap website using Pinegrow, everything looks fine in the software however I realized when I actually preview or upload the code to a browser parts of the website is being overridden, I just found out it's because of the bootstrap.min.css file.

The strange thing is my 'home', 'about me' pages are fine, however when it gets to 'skills', 'portfolio' etc pages the css from my custom file is overridden.

For example:
This is what my software shows
[Preview from Pinegrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4vKg.jpg)

And this is what happens when it is in a browser:
[Preview from Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWXim.jpg)

**Things I have done**

- Some people suggested just deleting the .min file, however doing that mucks up the website.
- `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"> 
  <!-- Custom CSS --> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/creative.css" type="text/css">` The custom css file is placed at the bottom in the html (someone said it provides priority to the custom file)
- Using the !important rule doesn't work and I don't think it's the right to use it
- I am using ID selections in CSS

Is the only solution to go into the .min file and edit the code from there? Is there a way to get my custom CSS code to override the .min instead? Would it help if i posted some of my code? Many thanks for your time.

Comment: Is there any way you can push this out to a server somewhere so we can view it in in the browser as opposed to images?

You shouldn't need to use "!important", no, unless you are targeting the same exact thing as what the bootstrap.min.css styles are targeting, and even then only when their styles happen to use important themselves (many actually do).

Comment: Are you sure that the second CSS file is being loaded into the browser correctly? Check the loaded sources, or see if the styling shows up as overridden in dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

I would have done so:
If a few page works, my opinion, problem in markup. If you don't use one header section for all pages, try to copy content from skills to about, then I would check the wrapper, and deeper structure first. Do you see any strange rules in development tools on skills page? (I'm learning, and I can only give you simple tips.)